# How to convert n-dimensional arrary into n-dimensional rotation matrix in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to convert n-dimensional array into n-dimensional rotation matrix using numpy.

Here is the code:

```
c = np.cos(angle)
s = np.sin(angle)
rot_z = np.array([[c, -s, 0], [s, c, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
```

I need to convert like below:

```
angle = [None]
c = np.cos(angle)
s = np.sin(angle)
rot_z = np.array([[c, -s, 0], [s, c, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

rot_z = [None,3,3]  # result
```

can anyone help me with this conversion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the `None` supposed to mean?

Comment: @hpaulj It is 1D array of shape None initially

Comment: The `0` and `1` have to be replaced by arrays matching `c` and `s` in shape.  You may need to use transpose to put this mystery `None` dimension first.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry I did not get what you mean. Could you please elaborate more?